# What are "virtual method numbers"?

Tags: c++, dll, dllexport, virtual-functions

I came across this statement, by a system architect. I do not understand this completely.

> In general it's better to export methods from a shared library with names instead of virtual method numbers, because these numbers tend to change without chance for the using application to detect.

What are "virtual method numbers", and could someone explain this in better detail?

EDIT

To explain the context, there were suggestions of using an interface class, to derive other classes, of a library, methods of whom could be used by other applications. When questioned, this was the reply, and was followed with :

```
 "...the idea is to remove the virtual method tables from the exports and replace by names. "
```

Comment: I think it's an implementation detail of one particular Microsoft compiler. Consult your platform documentation.

Comment: @KerrekSB It's certainly an implementation detail, but I suspect that what is meant is the index into the vtable, which most compilers use.

Comment: @JamesKanze: I can only speculate, but I think MS uses those numbers in the name mangling, so you can (must?) use them to perform dynamic symbol lookup. I think that's what the OP is driving at, and that's very specific to MS.

Comment: This might be possible to answer if you provided some context, such as where exactly you came across it.

Comment: @KerrekSB I don't see any trace of the numbers in the mangled names in the object file (using `dumpbin /symbols`).  It would be interesting to know the context of the statement; to me, it sounds like comments on how to implement exporting; if so: Microsoft (and everyone else I know of) exports the names.  In fact, I don't know how else you would do it, since most functions aren't virtual, or even members of a class.

Comment: Added the only other comment made to explain the context.

Comment: Two cases in Windows where methods are numbered.  First is late-bound COM, the *dispid* indicates the method to call.  It makes the client **more** resilient to server changes.  Second one is the ordinal for an exported function from a DLL.  A micro-optimization, very tedious to setup.  And irrelevant to an interface implementation, there isn't any way to convince the compiler to emit code to do a name lookup at runtime, implementation calls are always made through the (exported) v-table.